# Bit flag to enum not getting the right results

Tags: kotlin, enums, bitflags

In the below code, i'm trying to convert int bit flags to enum, but I'm not getting the right results.

### Enum Flags

```
enum class State {
    NONE = 0,
    FORWARD =4,
    BACKWARD =5, 
}
```

### Bit Flag and conversion

```
 infix fun Int.withFlag(flag: Int) = this or flag
    fun fromInt(value: Int) = values().mapNotNull {
        if (it.value.withFlag(value) == value ) it else null 
    }
```

### Action

```
 // backward
    val flag = 5
    State.fromInt(flag)
```

### Results

```
// results  NONE, FORWARD, BACKWARD
// expected BACKWARD
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
enum class State(val value: Int) {
    NONE(0),
    FORWARD(4),
    BACKWARD(5);

    companion object {
        fun getByVal(arg: Int) : State? = values().firstOrNull { it.value == arg }
    }
}

State.getByVal(5) //BACKWARD
State.getByVal(7) //null
```

Comment: I also need to support multiple bit exaple `println( State.getByVal(9) )//BACKWARD and FORWARD`

Comment: Sure, please change the `getByVal()` implementation to suit your needs. Also change the return type to be `List<State>`?. So in the given example how does `9` mean `Backward` and `Forward`? Some more examples would help. Could not make that out from the question itself.